# mysql trigger not working on insert

Tags: mysql

Table: items
Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `ite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemName` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ite_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `itemName` (`itemName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


delimiter |

create trigger item_beforeinsert before insert on items
    for each row begin
    if new.itemNumber < 50 then
        set new.ite_id = null;
    end if;
end;
|
```

now the following command doesn't cause a trigger

```
insert items( itemname, itemnumber) values ( 'xyz', 1 );
```

any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ite_ID is not null and you want to set it null with your trigger, beside that it's auto increment, so you wont be able to 'control' all the values to assign to that field, I.E it wont overwrite values

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for.  The trigger will work when used on a column that isn't auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be

```
insert INTO items( itemname, itemnumber) values ( 'xyz', 1 );
```

also, since you have set `ite_id` as `NOT NULL`, you can't use a `set new.ite_id = null;`

Comment: no, that's not the problem.  The insert is working, but the trigger isn't executing.  set new.ite_id = null is supposed to cause an error which stops the insert.

Answer (score 0):

For auto incremented primary key fields you can pass NULL value while inserting. MySQL automatically assigns auto generated value. It is not an error setting up NULL to it *BEFORE insert*. And hence trigger didn't fire an error.

**Example**:

```
insert into items( ite_id, ... ) values ( null, ... );
```

The above statement is valid and works, since `ite_id` field is primary key with auto increment.